# Difficulty in customising cartogram output in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, cartogram

I am able to produce a cartogram using cartogram::cartogram_cont() But then have difficulty in customising the styling.

I have used broom::tidy() and dplyr::left_join() to fortify the cartogram, but I think perhaps the tidy stage has interfered with the plotOrder. If possible, I will include the output cartograms.

I'm attempting to replicate this type of output, but within my locality. Plesae note that the dataset used for the weighting in cartogram_cont() is not particularly significant, just a proof of concept at this stage:

```
[R Graph Gallery][1]
  [1]: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/331-basic-cartogram/

Shapefile from: [Lle Shapefile Location][2]
  [2]: http://lle.gov.wales/catalogue/item/LocalAuthorities/?lang=en

library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(maptools)
library(cartogram)
library(devtools)
install_github("HanOostdijk/odataR" , build_vignettes = T)
library(odataR)
library(tidyr)
library(rgdal)
library(htmltools)




#Read in shapefile and transform shape
#dsn = folder name, layer = filename but drop the .shp

shapefile <- readOGR(dsn = "Wales Shapefile",
                     layer = "localauthoritiesPolygon") %>% 
#Transform coordinate referencing system
spTransform(CRS("+init=epsg:4326")) 


#Next step is to join an interesting dataset to the shapefile using dplyr, then pass this to the cartoram package to render.
#Gone for the teacher sickness dataset from Stats Wales. Noticed it's only up to 2017, wonder if they've stopped collecting. 

teacher_sickness_data <- odataR_query('http://open.statswales.gov.wales/dataset/schw0001')


#Check values for join.
categories <- unique(teacher_sickness_data$Area_ItemName_ENG)
categories_shp <- shapefile@data$name_en

categories
categories_shp

#Teacher data has "All Welsh local authorities". Not contained in shapefile so remove. 

UA_sickness_data <- teacher_sickness_data[-c(2, 4:6, 8, 9, 11:13, 15:17)] %>% 
  filter(Area_ItemName_ENG != "All Welsh local authorities")


#Perform join to shapefile

shapefile_1 <- shapefile %>%
 merge(UA_sickness_data, by.x = "name_en", by.y = "Area_ItemName_ENG",
       duplicateGeoms = TRUE)

#Shiny App will allow choice of inputs to achieve one row per polygon. However, for testing
#functionality with cartograph functions, perform test filtering.

data_filtered <- UA_sickness_data %>% 
  filter(Year_ItemName_ENG == 2017) %>% 
  filter(Type_ItemName_ENG == "Full-time") %>% 
  filter(Variable_ItemName_ENG == "Total days of sick leave")

test_merge <- shapefile %>%
  merge(data_filtered, by.x = "name_en", by.y = "Area_ItemName_ENG")



nc_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds",
                       domain = log(test_merge@data$Data))

m <-test_merge %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(weight = 1,
              color = ~nc_pal(log(Data)),
              label = ~name_en,
              highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 3,
                                           color = "crimson",
                                           bringToFront = TRUE),
              popup = ~ paste0(Variable_ItemName_ENG, "<br/>",
                               "<b/>",
                               Data))

m

wales_cart <- cartogram_cont(test_merge, "Data", itermax=5)
plot(wales_cart)
[![Wales_Cartogram][3]][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tsMC.png


library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(broom)
library(rgeos) #used for gBuffer

#Buffer allows to tidy cartogram based on factor of choice. 
wales_cart_buffered <- gBuffer(wales_cart, byid=TRUE, width=0)


#tidy cartogram in order to pass to ggplot
spdf_fortified_wales <- tidy(wales_cart_buffered, region = "name_en")


#Now perform a join based on english UA names
spdf_fortified_wales_joined <- spdf_fortified_wales %>%
  left_join(. , wales_cart@data, by=c("id"="name_en")) 



ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = spdf_fortified_wales_joined, aes(fill = Data, x = long, y = lat, group = "name_en") , size=0, alpha=0.9) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void()

[![incorrect_ggplot][4]][4]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/as0Z4.png

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = spdf_fortified_wales_joined, aes(fill = Data, x = long, y = lat, group = "name_en") , size=0, alpha=0.9) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void()
Success Criteria: Polygons are rendered correctly distorted and colour scale reflects weighting variable.
```

Comment: We don't have your data, so if there's an issue with it, all we can do it guess. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example. If you know your data has gotten out of order, have you tried sorting it back again? Also, you have shortcodes for the same image twice—I put them inline how they are in your post, but you probably forgot to upload one.

Comment: Thanks @camille as you can see I'm quite the noob. Yes I wondered about sharing the shapefiles and couldn't think of an easy option. Perhaps sharing the URL sources? I will have a look through your link article and improve my question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with your formatting but none of the images are showing now

Comment: Hi @Camille, not sure if it's because my reputation isn't high enough to allow me to post images.